# Nested Resources in Same Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-resources

I've been following a tutorial and after finishing it decided to try and continue with features of my own. I currently have a `listing model`, a `comment model`, a `thumbs up model`, a `thumbs down` model and a `flag model`. Users can comment on a listing, give it a thumbs up, thumbs down or flag it. So far I've only got to allowing users to comment on a listing and allowing users to give a thumbs up (like).

```
resources :listings do
resources :comments
resources :likes
end
```

Is there a limit to how many nested a resources a single resource can have? or can I continue like so:

```
resources :listings do
resources :comments
resources :likes
resources :dislikes
resources :flags
end
```

The reason for my question is I can't find a decent explanation anywhere for what I might intend to do later. A user can comment on a listing or like/dislike/thumbs up/thumbs down the listing but if I wanted to allow users to also like/dislike a users comment, I'm sure the routes would have to change (but not sure how the nesting would work)

```
resources :listings do
resources :comments do
resources :commentlikes
end
resources :listinglikes
end
```

Anyone that can provide resources or a general explanation would be a great help.

Comment: Check out Polymorphic Associations ( http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations ) You can have several models to be "commentable", "likeable", etc.

Comment: You should have a look at thumbs_up gem https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up